# Convert .dat File to .xls file

Tags: linux, perl

I am using automation to download a .dat file and parse it using excel parser module in perl.
But whenever i tried to access the .dat file it says not a valid excel file. (all these operation has been done in linux)

As a work around I have moved the .dat file to windows machine and opened it using excel file.
Then saved the .dat file as an excel file in windows. Then resend that file to Linux machine. Now the perl script can parse the file.

Instead of this long path can I convert the .dat file to excel file in linux itself?
If yes then how?

First Few Lines from my .dat file :

F_NF_CD ART_GRP_NO      ART_GRP_DESCR   ART_GRP_SUB_NO  ART_GRP_SUB_DESCR       ART_NO  ART_DESC        SELL_UNIT       PACK_TYPE       SELL_PR VAT_PERC        MRP_PRICE       STOCK   ART_STATUS      EXTRA_INFO      BLOCK_IND

F       191     HYGIENE PAPERS  3       LADIE'S HYGIENE 287432  SOFY SIDE WALLS LARGE SOFT15P   1       EA      89.8    5       99      47      1       SELL

F       191     HYGIENE PAPERS  3       LADIE'S HYGIENE 287422  SOFY SIDE WALLS REGULAR SOFT15P 1       EA      80.73   5       89      0       1       SELL

Comment: Please, show format of your *.dat files.

Comment: Can you open (and read) the *.dat file with a text editor or is it binary? You can do a `file foo.dat` on your linux box. That should also tell us about the nature of the file.

Comment: Are you able to open this *.dat file with LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: This is text file, I can open and read. >>> file foo.dat gives ISO-8859 text

Comment: After I opened it in windows and saved it as xls and bring it back to linux. For the new xls file >>>> file foo.xls is showing CDF V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 5.1, Code page: 1252, Last Saved By: Administrator, Create Time/Date: Wed Jul 11 06:13:41 2012, Last Saved Time/Date: Wed Jul 11 06:13:41 2012, Security: 0

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your *.dat file, please? You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11447567/edit) and add them. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask - I'm fairly certain you don't even need need the Excel step at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the script tries to read the meta data of a file before parsing it. If the module see the metadata is not excel it won't proceed further. So it is important to change the metadata of the .dat file to .xls.  Which i dont think possible without proper conversion tool.